# Regex for email address anomaly

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to match an email address with the following 2 regex'es and cant figure why the second one is wrong. The only difference being the position of the underscore.

```
import re

a='dheeraj-234@gmail.com'

print bool(re.search('[a-z][a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{1,3}',a))

print bool(re.search('[a-z][a-z0-9.-_]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{1,3}',a))
```

Answer:

```
True
False
```

Comment: You haven't escaped `-`, so `.-_` matches characters "between" `.` and `_`. See e.g. http://regex101.com for interactive regex debugging with explanations.

Comment: @Jonrsharpe - Maybe you should make a full answer.  That looks like the answer.

Comment: note that this regex would fail on a lot of emails...

Comment: [Regex is not the right tool for validating email addresses.](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @Thomas Ayoub this is for a question i was solving with certain specific demands as to how the emails are going to be

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's it! thanks